# Displaying error messages from Node API on FrontEnd console (React App)

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, error-handling

I'm building Node & React application and I'm working on authentication now. For example when someone will type e-mail that already exist in database, I would like to send a response with error with proper status and message that email already exist.

I'm already done with sending errors when it's needed. Problem is that even if I pass error message within, I can not display it on frontend.

back-end (Node):

```
 User.find({ email: email })
        .then(user => {
            if (user.length >= 1) {
                return res.status(409).json({
                    message: 'Mail exists' // <-- I want to pass message here
                })
            }
```

front-end (React):

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/user/signup', newUser)
            .then(response=> {
                dispatch({
                    type: actionTypes.SIGNUP_SUCCESS
                })
                localStorage.setItem('JWT_TOKEN', response.data.token)
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = response.data.token
            })
            .catch((err)=> {
                console.log(err.message) // <-- I want to display message here
            })
```

My actual result is that i see `Request failed with status code 409` in my console.
Therefore I would like to see `Mail exists`.
Thank You for help :)
Best regards.

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(err) on the response in the catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// you can try below code in your catch block

.catch((err)=> {
 // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
 // that falls out of the range of 2xx
  if (err.response) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
    console.log(error.response.status);
    console.log(error.response.headers);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mohammed, you can find error message under data property.

```
console.log(error.response.data.message);
```